# Send files via cURL post PHP. XML or plain text?

Tags: php, xml, curl

So I've been working for around two months with cURL post requests via php and when it's about sending files I've been using the **.txt** extension files and my questions are:

Is it better (or even possible) to send the data as a **.xml** file?

And if yes, `curl_file_create()` function also works with **.xml** files or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: They are multiple approaches on how to send files with PHP. Please post the code of your approach. But in general: sure, you can send any type of data with curl.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it better to send the data as a .xml file?

Yes. No. Maybe.

It depends on what the server expects you to send.

It depends on what format is most suitable for expressing the information you are sending.

JPEG might be the best format!

> curl_file_create() function also works with .xml files

It deals with *files*. Nowhere does it say it only deals with particular types of file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!